# how do I extract an ip address from within a script

Tags: java, android, kotlin

##### I am a beginner in the Kotlin language. I want to extract a group of ip from the text. Can you help me?

```kotlin
var ip= sting.split("[a-z]".toRegex())

println(ip)

//need output
 
//192.168.0.1
//148.99.65.103
```

- var string ="""
  hello
  192.168.0.1
  test
  192.168.0.22
  kotlin
  192.168.0.115

"""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val regex = """((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)""".toRegex()
    
val str1= "hello 192.168.0.1 test 192.168.0.22 kotlin 192.168.0.115"

var matchResult = regex.find(str1)

while (matchResult != null) {
      println( matchResult!!.value)
      matchResult = matchResult.next()
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer..I need the opposite method, which is to show the IP
192.168.0.1 only

Comment: What is the opposite  method? If you can find multiple IP Addresses, what is your so-called rule that only `192.168.0.1` is required? Just the first one? Is there any special rule? Or is `192.168.0.1` hard-coded, just find out if `192.168.0.1` is included?

Comment: i need all ip address  192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.214 and .....

Comment: `val regex = """( 192.168.0.1 )""".toRegex()`